# What does the log message "Not subject to any constraint" mean in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have a very simple Jersey 2.x rest endpoint running in tomcat.  For every single request to the end point, I get this log output:

```
FINE: Security checking request POST /myurl/s
Aug 28, 2015 7:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Not subject to any constraint
Aug 28, 2015 7:17:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper allocate
FINER:   Returning non-STM instance
```

here is the code:

```
@Path("myurl")
public class MyEndPoint extends BaseRawInfoEndPoint {
    @POST
    @Path("s")
    //@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void saveStuff(String rawJson) throws JsonProcessingException {
        //persist code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see it logged [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L502). The request goes through the authentication mechanism of Tomcat. If there are no constraints set, then it will be logged as such and the method will return and move on.

The security constraints are from the Servlet specification. You can read more about them [here in the EE tutorial: 48.2.1 Specifying Security Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#GKBAA). The constraints are to configure the authentication and access control mechanism, and they should be configured in the web.xml file.

**See Also:**

- [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Configuring%20a%20Realm). If you want to test out the security constraints, you will need to configure the realm in Tomcat, as you will need to specify the realm in the web.xml